# Unable to access retention information. No data returned using YouTube's API's

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to pull retention data for my videos.

I am able to access the title, description and total views but when I try to pull up retention data, the API returns 0 rows.

I can use the same information and pull up other time based datasets like Daily Watch time without any issues.

I've tried to do this two ways.

1. Using the online query tools found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query
2. Building my own python script

```py
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import json

# Access Info

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'Blah'
VIDEO_ID = 'Blah'
CLIENT_ID = 'Blah'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'Blah'

def get_video_info(youtube_data, video_id):
response = youtube_data.videos().list(
part='snippet',
id=video_id
).execute()

    if response.get('items'):
        video = response['items'][0]
        title = video['snippet']['title']
        print(f'Video Title: {title}')
        return video
    else:
        print('Video not found')
        return None

def get_retention_data(access_token, video_id, client_id, client_secret):
try:
\# Build the YouTube Analytics API client
credentials = Credentials(access_token, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
print("Credentials:", credentials)
youtube_analytics = build('youtubeAnalytics', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
youtube_data = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        # Fetch the video info
        video_info = get_video_info(youtube_data, VIDEO_ID)
    
        # Set the required parameters for the API call
        start_date = '2023-04-10'
        end_date = '2023-04-12'
        metrics = 'relativeRetentionPerformance'
        dimensions = 'elapsedVideoTimeRatio'
    
        # Build the API request
        request = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
            ids='channel==MINE',
            startDate=start_date,
            endDate=end_date,
            metrics=metrics,
            dimensions=dimensions,
            filters=f'video=={video_id}'
        )
    
        # Print the API request URL
        print("API Request URL:", request.to_json())
    
        # Execute the API request
        response = request.execute()
    
        # Print the response
        print("API Response:")
        print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
    
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
        response = None
    
    return response

def save_retention_data_to_file(data, filename='retention_data.json'):
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
print(f'Retention data saved to {filename}')

# Call the function to get the retention data

retention_data = get_retention_data(ACCESS_TOKEN, VIDEO_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

# Save the retention data to a file

save_retention_data_to_file(retention_data)
```

With both methods, I can access the video information but not the retention data. I've tried this across multiple videos with retention data and the end result is still the same.